# syb_describe in DBD::Sybase

Tags: perl, sybase

I am looking to extract Sybase datatype for all the columns in a table. When I try to achieve this using `$sth->{TYPE}`, I get a numeric version of the datatype (i.e. instead of sybase datatype `varchar`, I get `0`).

From the DBD::Sybase documentation, I noticed that `SYBTYPE` attribute of `syb_describe` function might be able to produce what I am looking for. But it seems that my understanding is not proper. `SYBTYPE` also prints datatype in numeric form only.

Is there any way to fetch the textual representation of actual Sybase datatype (instead of the number)?

Comment: Accepted some of the helpful answers now.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you wish to *reverse engineer* the create table definition.  Here is an SQL script you can use for Sybase or SQL Server tables.

```
select c.name,
        "type(size)"=case
                     when t.name in ("char", "varchar") then
                          t.name + "(" + rtrim(convert(char(3), c.length)) + ")"
                     else t.name
                     end,
       "null"=case
              when convert(bit, (c.status & 8)) = 0 then "NOT NULL"
              else "NULL"
              end
from syscolumns c, systypes t
where c.id = object_id("my_table_name")
and   c.usertype *= t.usertype
order by c.colid
go
```

Note: This could still be edited with a nawk script to create a real SQL schema file.
The nawk script would strip the header, add "create table my_table_name", add commas, strip the footer and add a "go".

Good SQL, good night!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround (Note: This does not answer the question though):

What I did was simply joined the `sysobjects`, `systypes` and `syscolumns` system tables.